# Can Spotlight index HTML files on Mojave?

Tags: macos, spotlight, search, html

Spotlight doesn't index HTML files on my machine. In the prefpane there's no option for webpages or .htm or .html file extensions. Google can't find a plugin for these files. I have 36,703 such files I need to index the content of. Help! Thank you.

Comment: HTML files are counted as "Developer" files in the Spotlight pref pane.

Comment: Thanks -- that box is checked.

Comment: Then I would reindex Spotlight.

Comment: Ohmygod it WORKS. Interesting -- I reindexed Spotlight as the first step in troubleshooting, and there was no change. I reindexed a second time, at your suggestion, and it now functions fine. _Thank_you_.

Comment: Are you the same benwiggy who's so helpful on https://notat.io/?